# problemas para reproducir videos

Tags: upgrade

No he podido reproducir videos que suben en canales de televisión colombiana, al tratar de reproducir me aparece que el video no está codificado para mi dispositivo; aparentemente instale el adobeflash player, pero la verdad no se como hacerlo; incluso juegos como Sims social en facebook no me abren porque según hay una instalación incorrecta. Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias

---

Google translate

I could not play videos that come up in Colombian television channels , to try to reproduce the video I get no code for my device ; apparently install the Adobe Flash player , but I really do not know how to do it; even games like Sims Social on Facebook not open because according to me there is an incorrect installation. Hopefully someone can help . Thank you

Comment: In english please.

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail? What did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. And please use a translation service like [Google Translate](//translate.google.com/), if you don't speak English. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))